# Does $L_{p}(\mu, X)^*=L_{q} (\mu, X^*)$ hold for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

I'm reading *Theorem 1* at page 98 of *Vector Measures* by Joseph Diestel, John Jerry Uhl.

> **THEOREM 1.** Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a **finite** measure space, $1 \leq p<\infty$, and $X$ be a Banach space. Then $L_{p}(\mu, X)^*=L_{q} (\mu, X^*)$ where $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$, if and only if $X^{*}$ has the Radon-Nikodým property with respect to $\mu$.

I would like to extend it to $\sigma$-finite measure space. However, I'm stuck at proving that $\varphi$ is an isometry. Could you elaborate on how to prove it?

Thank you so much!

---

**My attempt:** Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space. There is a countable measurable partition $(\Omega_n)$ of $\Omega$ such that $\mu(\Omega_n) < \infty$. Let $\mu_n(A) := \mu(A \cap \Omega_n)$ for all $n$. Then

- $\mu_n$ is concentrated on $\Omega_n$,
- $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu_n)$ is a finite measure space, and
- $\mu = \sum \mu_n$.

By **Theorem 1**, for each $n$ there is an isometric isomorphism
$$
\varphi_n : L_{p}(\mu_n, X)^* \to L_{q} (\mu_n, X^*).
$$

For $H \in L_{p}(\mu, X)^*$, we define $H_n \in L_{p}(\mu_n, X)^*$ by
$$
H_n (f) := H (f 1_{\Omega_n}) \quad \forall f \in L_{p}(\mu_n, X).
$$

Notice that $\varphi_n (H_n)$ is just an equivalence class of $L_{q} (\mu_n, X^*)$. If $g$ is a representative of $\varphi_n (H_n)$, then $g$ can take **any** value of $X^*$ on $\Omega \setminus \Omega_n$ and thus $\|g\|_{L_{q} (\mu_m, X^*)}$ can be $+\infty$ for some $m \neq n$. To avoid this situation, we define
$$
\varphi : L_{p}(\mu, X)^* \to L_{q} (\mu, X^*), H \mapsto \sum_n \varphi_n (H_n) 1_{\Omega_n}.
$$

It's straightforward to verify $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. Let's prove that it is an isometry. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\| \varphi (H) \|_{ L_{q} (\mu, X^*)}^q &= \int \bigg \| \sum_n \varphi_n (H_n) 1_{\Omega_n} \bigg \|_{X^{*}}^q \mathrm d \mu \\
&= \sum_m \int \bigg \| \sum_n \varphi_n (H_n) 1_{\Omega_n} \bigg \|_{X^{*}}^q  \mathrm d \mu_m \\
&= \sum_m \int \big \| \varphi_m (H_m) \big \|_{X^{*}}^q \mathrm d \mu_m \\
&= \sum_m \| \varphi_m (H_m) \|_{ L_{q} (\mu_m, X^*)}^q \\
&= \sum_m \|H_m\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)^*}.
\end{align}
$$

So it suffices to prove that
$$
\|H\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu, X)^*} = \sum_m \|H_m\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)^*}.
$$

By Hölder's inequality,
$$
\begin{align}
\left [ \frac{|H(f)|}{\|f\|_{L_{p}(\mu, X)}} \right ]^q =  \frac{\big |\sum_m H_m(f) \big |^q}{\left [\sum_m \|f\|^p_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)} \right]^{q/p}} \le \sum_m \left [ \frac{|H_m (f)|}{\|f\|_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)}} \right ]^q \quad \forall f \in L_{p}(\mu, X).
\end{align}
$$

As such,
$$
\|H\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu, X)^*} \le \sum_m \|H_m\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)^*}.
$$

Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Pick $f_m \in L_{p}(\mu_m, X)$ such that
$$
\left [ \frac{|H_m (f_m)|}{\|f_m\|_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)}} \right ]^q > \|H_m\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)^*} - \varepsilon 2^{-m}.
$$

WLOG, we can assume
$$
H_m (f_m) \ge 0 \quad \forall m \in \mathbb N^*.
$$

Then
$$
\sum_m \left [ \frac{|H_m (f_m)|}{\|f_m\|_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)}} \right ]^q > \sum_m \|H_m\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)^*} - \varepsilon.
$$

It remains to prove that
$$
\sum_{m=1}^n \left [ \frac{|H_m (f_m)|}{\|f_m\|_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)}} \right ]^q \le \|H\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu, X)^*}.
$$

It suffices to prove that there is $f \in L_{p}(\mu, X)$ such that
$$
 \left [ \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{|H_m (f_m)|}{\|f_m\|_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)}} \right ]^q \le   \left [  \frac{|H (f)|}{\|f\|_{L_{p}(\mu, X)}} \right ]^q.
$$

Comment: Hint: check that $\|L\|^q = \sum \|L_n\|^q$.

Comment: @NikWeaver I'm able to prove that $\|L\|^q \le \sum \|L_n\|^q$. However, I failed to prove the reverse inequality. Could you have a check on my update?

Comment: Now show that $\|L\|^q \geq \sum_1^n \|L_k\|^q$ for any $n$.

Comment: Did you try the simple fact that every $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu$ is of the form $\mu= \varphi\cdot \nu$ for a *finite* measure $\nu$ and a density $\varphi:\Omega \to (0,\infty)$?

Comment: @NikWeaver I have tried but fail to prove the existence of such $f$ that $$\left [ \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{|H_m (f_m)|}{\|f_m\|_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)}} \right ]^q \le   \left [  \frac{|H (f)|}{\|f\|_{L_{p}(\mu, X)}} \right ]^q$$? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth It seems I got your idea. I will try to formalize it. On the other hand, I'm curious if my failed approach can be fixed...

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I have formalized your idea [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4576340/generalize-theorem-1-in-diestel-uhls-vector-measures). It's elegant!

Comment: @NikWeaver I'm sorry if I'm bothering you. Could you please have a look at my update and elaborate on how to finish the reverse inequality? I would like to learn it very much...

Comment: Well, a quick way to do it is by applying Theorem 1 to $\Omega_1 \cup \ldots \cup \Omega_n$. The isometry it gives is just the isometry for each $k$, patched together.

Comment: @NikWeaver Could you have a check on my below answer? It seems the proof depends an a special property (the **Lemma**) of the canonical isometric isomorphism.

Comment: Yeah, looks fine.  Good for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my formalization of @Nik's hints to finish the proof.

---

Let's prove that
$$
\sum_{m=1}^M \|H_m\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)^*} \le \|H\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu, X)^*} \quad \forall M \in \mathbb N^*.
$$

Let $\Omega' := \bigcup_{m=1}^M \Omega_m$. We define a measure $\mu'$ on $\Omega$ by
$$
\mu' (B) := \mu(B \cap \Omega') \quad \forall B \in \Sigma.
$$

Let $\varphi' : L_{p}(\mu', X)^* \to L_{q} (\mu', X^*)$ be the canonical isometric isomorphism, i.e.,
$$
K (f) = \int_\Omega \langle \varphi'(K), f \rangle \mathrm d \mu' \quad \forall K \in L_{p}(\mu', X)^*, \forall f \in L_{p}(\mu', X).
$$

Then we have

> [Lemma](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434787/if-h-in-l-q-mu-x-such-that-int-langle-h-f-rangle-mathrm-d-mu) Let $N \in \Sigma$ and $K \in L_{p}(\mu', X)^*$ such that $K(f1_N)=0$ for all $f \in L_{p}(\mu', X)$. Then $\varphi'(K)=0$ on $N$.

We define $H' ,H'_m \in L_{p}(\mu', X)^*$ by
$$
H' (f) := H (f 1_{\Omega'}) \quad H'_m (f) := H (f 1_{\Omega_m})  \quad \forall f \in L_{p}(\mu', X).
$$

Then $H' = \sum_{m=1}^M H'_m$. Also,
$$
\|  H'\|_{L_{p}(\mu', X)^*} \le \|H\|_{L_{p}(\mu, X)^*}
\quad \text{and} \quad 
\|H'_m\|_{L_{p}(\mu', X)^*} = \|H_m\|_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)^*}.
$$

By our **Lemma**, the supports of $\{\varphi'(H'_m)\}_{m=1}^M$ are pairwise disjoint and thus justifies $(\star)$ below. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^M \|H_m\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu_m, X)^*} &= \sum_{m=1}^M \|H'_m\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu', X)^*} \\
 &= \sum_{m=1}^M \|\varphi'(H'_m) \|^q_{L_{q}(\mu', X^*)} \\
&\overset{(\star)}{=}  \bigg \| \sum_{m=1}^M \varphi' (H'_m) \bigg \|^q_{L_{q}(\mu', X^*)} \\
&= \bigg \|  \varphi'\bigg (\sum_{m=1}^MH'_m \bigg) \bigg \|^q_{L_{q}(\mu', X^*)} \\
&= \bigg \|\sum_{m=1}^MH'_m \bigg\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu', X)^*} \\
&= \|  H'\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu', X)^*} \\
&\le \|H\|^q_{L_{p}(\mu, X)^*}.
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.